# Google Footer Color Bar CSS

Tags: html, css

How Google made the color bar located at their footer of [this page](https://www.google.nl/intl/nl/policies/privacy/).

Is it possible to make this in CSS and have it expand 100% of width ?

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is very possible

Answer (score 0):

This is quite easy to do in CSS. Make a div(in this case `.googlebar`) that has 100% width, and however high you want(I chose `5px`).
Then, place 4 spans inside, display them inline-block, set the width to 25%(since there is 4 of them), and the height to 100%.
 All that is left to do is change the colors, and you are done :

```css
.googlebar{
  width:100%;
  height:5px;
}
.googlebar span{
  display:inline-block;
  width:25%;
  height:100%;
}
.googlebar span.blue{
  background:#0089FA;
}
.googlebar span.red{
  background:#FF002B;
}
.googlebar span.orange{
  background:#FFA900;
}
.googlebar span.green{
  background:#00A753;
}
```

```html
<div class="googlebar">
  <span class="blue"></span><span class="red"></span><span class="orange"></span><span class="green"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it for you: https://jsfiddle.net/xtat0oa6/1/

HTML

```
<div class="footer">
  <div class="div1">

  </div>
  <div class="div2">

  </div>
  <div class="div3">

  </div>
  <div class="div4">

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.footer {
  margin-top: calc(100vh - 5px);
}

.div1 {
  width: 25%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
}

.div2 {
  width: 25%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
}

.div3 {
  width: 25%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: orange;
  float: left;
}

.div4 {
  width: 25%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
}
```